# MVC save a list of radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button

want to create an online test page
My project includes several models including and a View model

There is a way for me to save a list of responses with a key in the database?

I do not know javascript, so I prefer to do it without using javascript.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(AnswerSelected => AnswerSelected.Course.AnswerSelected,2, new { @Name = item.TestNumber }) @item.AnswerOne
```

Comment: Of course you can (and you do not need javascript). But you have not shown any if the relevant code. What is you model? What are the controller methods? And under no circumstances do you ever change the `name` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Models;
using Models.ViewModel;

namespace Royan.Controllers
{
    public class CourseExamTestsController : Controller
    {     
        private DBContextRoyan db = new DBContextRoyan();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {    
            Course_Exam_Tests VM_Test = new Course_Exam_Tests();
            VM_Test.Tests = db.Tests.ToList().OrderBy(s => s.TestNumber);
            return View(VM_Test);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(Course_Exam_Tests VM_Course)
        {
            Course CoursedbObj = VM_Course.Course;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Course VMCourse = new Course();
                VMCourse.ID = new Guid();
                db.Courses.Add(CoursedbObj);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View("Result");
        }
        public ActionResult Result()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    namespace Models
    {
        namespace Models.ViewModel
    {
        public class Course_Exam_Tests
        {
            public Course Course { get; set; }
            public Exam Exam { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Test> Tests { get; set; }
        }
    }

        namespace Models
    {
        public class Test : BaseEntityActive
        {
            public Test()
            {
            }
            private int _testNumber;
            [Required]
            [Index(IsUnique = true)]
            public int TestNumber
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_testNumber==0)
                    {
                        return (0);
                    }
                    return _testNumber;
                }
                set
                {
                    _testNumber = value;
                }
            }
            private string _question;
            [Required]
            public string Question
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_question==null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _question;
                }
                set
                {
                    _question = value;
                }
            }
            private string _answerOne;
            [Required]
            public string AnswerOne
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_answerOne==null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _answerOne;
                }
                set
                {
                    _answerOne = value;
                }
            }
            private string _answerTwo;
            [Required]
            public string AnswerTwo
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_answerTwo == null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _answerTwo;
                }
                set
                {
                    _answerTwo = value;
                }
            }
            private string _answerThree;
            [Required]
            public string AnswerThree
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_answerThree == null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _answerThree;
                }
                set
                {
                    _answerThree = value;
                }
            }
            private string _answerFour;
            [Required]
            public string AnswerFour
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_answerFour == null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _answerFour;
                }
                set
                {
                    _answerFour = value;
                }
            }
            private string _descriptionAnswer;

            public string DescriptionAnswer
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_descriptionAnswer == null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _descriptionAnswer;
                }
                set
                {
                    _descriptionAnswer = value;
                }
            }
            private int _correctAnswer;
            [Required]
            [Range(1,4)]
            public int CorrectAnswer
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_correctAnswer==0)
                    {
                        return (_correctAnswer=0);
                    }
                    return _correctAnswer;
                }
                set
                {
                    _correctAnswer = value;
                }
            }
            public Guid ExamID { get; set; }
            public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
        }
    }

    test model

    namespace Models
    {
        public class Test : BaseEntityActive
        {
            public Test()
            {
            }
            private int _testNumber;
            [Required]
            [Index(IsUnique = true)]
            public int TestNumber
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_testNumber==0)
                    {
                        return (0);
                    }
                    return _testNumber;
                }
                set
                {
                    _testNumber = value;
                }
            }
            private string _question;
            [Required]
            public string Question
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_question==null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _question;
                }
                set
                {
                    _question = value;
                }
            }
            private string _answerOne;
            [Required]
            public string AnswerOne
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_answerOne==null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _answerOne;
                }
                set
                {
                    _answerOne = value;
                }
            }
            private string _answerTwo;
            [Required]
            public string AnswerTwo
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_answerTwo == null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _answerTwo;
                }
                set
                {
                    _answerTwo = value;
                }
            }
            private string _answerThree;
            [Required]
            public string AnswerThree
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_answerThree == null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _answerThree;
                }
                set
                {
                    _answerThree = value;
                }
            }
            private string _answerFour;
            [Required]
            public string AnswerFour
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_answerFour == null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _answerFour;
                }
                set
                {
                    _answerFour = value;
                }
            }
            private string _descriptionAnswer;

            public string DescriptionAnswer
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_descriptionAnswer == null)
                    {
                        return (string.Empty);
                    }
                    return _descriptionAnswer;
                }
                set
                {
                    _descriptionAnswer = value;
                }
            }
            private int _correctAnswer;
            [Required]
            [Range(1,4)]
            public int CorrectAnswer
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_correctAnswer==0)
                    {
                        return (_correctAnswer=0);
                    }
                    return _correctAnswer;
                }
                set
                {
                    _correctAnswer = value;
                }
            }
            public Guid ExamID { get; set; }
            public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
        }
    }
Course Model
namespace Models
{
    public class Course : BaseEntityActive
    {
        public Course()
        {
        }
        private int _courseNumber;
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

        public int CourseNumber
        {
            get
            {
                if (_courseNumber == 0)
                {
                    return (0);
                }
                return _courseNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _courseNumber = value;
            }
        }
        private string _answerSelected;

        public string AnswerSelected
        {
            get
            {
                if (_answerSelected == null)
                {
                    return (string.Empty);
                }
                return _answerSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                _answerSelected = value;
            }
        }
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
        public Guid ExamID { get; set; }
        public virtual User Users { get; set; }
        public virtual Exam Exams { get; set; }
    }
}
```